# Multi-Site Licence

Tags: craft3, license, multi-domain

We will build two Pages with two different domains.

We want to use the multi-site feature of Craft 3 so we only need one backend.

I see on YouTube a Video from Mijingo - "Multi-Site in Craft 3" and he use two domains in one backend.

Can we use one licence or need we two licences for this?

Answer (score 1):

If the two different domains are for the same "site", i.e. they have common things between them you can share, then yes - you can use one license for them.

Craft's multi-site functionality isn't really designed for sites that have completely content that don't have anything in common in mind.

Related documentation: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html#app